# Question about nested conditional expectation.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, control-theory, conditional-expectation, kalman-filter

Question 1: I am interested in finding out, why the following is or is not the case:

$\mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbb{E} \left[( X_k|(Y_0,Y_1,...,Y_{k-1}) )|( Y_k|(Y_0,Y_1,...,Y_{k-1}) )\right]|(Y_0,Y_1,...,Y_{k-1}) \right] =  \mathbb{E} \left[X_k|(Y_0,Y_1,...,Y_{k}) \right] $

where $X_i, Y_j$ are random variables in $\mathbb{R}^n$? Or, is there way to break up the expectation on the right which is conditioned on measurements up to $Y_k$, into terms which involve the condiotional expectation with respect to $Y_1,...,Y_{k-1}$

**Background:** This question arises in probabilistic Kalman-Filtering derivation, where we are trying to simplify the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E} \left[X_k|(Y_0,Y_1,...,Y_{k}) \right]$ (Minimum-Variance Estimate of State $X_k$ based on measurements $(Y_0,Y_1,...,Y_{k})$ up until time $k$) by trying to compute it iteratively based on on our already computed estimates based on the information of $(Y_0,Y_1,...,Y_{k-1})$. This part of the derivation is a crucial part, as it motivates and derives the iterative approach of computing the estimates of the Kalman Filter. Reading through literature, the explanation at this part, which connects the computation of estimates of one time-step to another,  is never detailed enough for me. Backwards engineering suggests to me though, that the presented conditional expectation formula must have been used to complete the derivation. That's why I am asking for a proof or counterexample of the above statement.

Question 2: In case, the above formula is not true, is there any related formula, which would suite the purpose of the described derivation?

**EDIT:**

I think I found my question and answer at the same time:

More proper question:

Q: Given the probability density function $f\left( \left.x_k,y_k\right|y_0,y_1,...,y_{k-1}\right)$, how do I find $E(x_k|y_0,...,y_k)$?

A: 
\begin{align}
E(x_k|y_0,...,y_k) &= \int\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty} x_k f\left( \left.x_k\right|y_0,y_1,...,y_{k-1},y_{k}\right) dx_k = \int\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty} x_k \frac{f\left(x_k,y_0,y_1,...,y_{k-1},y_{k}\right)}{f\left(y_0,y_1,...,y_{k-1},y_{k}\right)} dx_k\\
&=\int\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty} x_k \frac{f\left(x_k,y_0,y_1,...,y_{k-1},y_{k}\right)}{f\left(y_0,y_1,...,y_{k-1},y_{k}\right)}\frac{f\left(y_0,y_1,...,y_{k-1}\right)}{f\left(y_0,y_1,...,y_{k-1}\right)} dx_k\\
&=\int\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty} x_k \frac{f\left(\left.x_k,y_k\right|y_0,...,y_{k-1}\right)}{f\left(\left.y_k\right|y_0,...,y_{k-1}\right)} dx_k
\end{align}

We basically obtain $E(\left.x_k\right|y_0,...,y_k)$ by building the conditional expectation of $x_k$ given $y_k$, both conditioned on $(y_0,...,y_k-1)$. Not knowing how to otherwise express this operation, I formulated this calculation as

$\mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbb{E} \left[( x_k|(y_0,y_1,...,y_{k-1}) )|( y_k|(y_0,y_1,...,y_{k-1}) )\right]|(y_0,y_1,...,y_{k-1}) \right] =  \mathbb{E} \left[x_k|(y_0,y_1,...,y_{k}) \right] $

which received some bad resonance from our online audience.

My final question or help for advice would be though, how would you otherwise write down this computation. Speaking non-mathematically/inproper, it is just the building of the conditional expectation of one random variable given another random variable, were both random variables each have distributions conditioned on the same set of other ($y_0,...y_{k-1}$) random variables? Please, give me some insight how to express this more mathematically rigorous.

Comment: You seem to believe that the chain of characters $U|V$ in formulas such as $E(U|V)$ refers to an actual random variable. It does not.

Comment: I am aware and stated that I am not understanding this topic right now, therefore the question. Not sure, why I receive a downvote.

Comment: @Did, can't $E(U,V)$ be seen as a function the random variable $V$ and hence is random variable? What does $U|V$ refer to exactly, isn't it a map, which maps every realization of V to a random variable $U|V$?

Comment: Sorry but E(U,V) does not exist, only E(U) does, and there is no random variable U|V, only E(U|V).

Comment: Ok, it seems like I am using the wrong language here to define my problem. Can you give me a reference, where I could have good introduction on this topic of conditional probability/ expectation?

Comment: Also, do you understand, where I am trying to get at or is the problem statement so ill-posed that the purpose is even unclear and it can not be answered?

Comment: What you seem to be after is a decomposition based on Bayes formula in the context of Kalman filters. Feeding these keywords into a search engine should produce wealths of web resources on the subject.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22499/discussion-between-dimitar-ho-and-did).

Comment: You are aiming at the Tower Rule or Law of Total Expectation. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)

Comment: What were the results of the discussion?